# Undefined symbol SystemInit(referred from startup_stm32f2xx.o) while building using Keil STM32

Tags: stm32, keil

I am using STM32F207VC controller. and I am using uvision4 IDE, When I try to compile a simple code, I get the error tst1.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol SystemInit (referred from startup_stm32f2xx.o). . I have place stm32f2x file to my project directory.

But still the same problem.

Please help in resolving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

"Libraries\CMSIS\CM3\DeviceSupport\ST\STM32F10x\system_stm32f10x.c" 
is needed it be added, as `SystemInit()` is defined within it.

Comment: nice your solution:)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should define (or take it from somewhere) function SystemInit, since it is called from startup.s file.

Or you can comment lines in startup file, where SystemInit function is called. There will be something like:

```
1 IMPORT  SystemInit
2 IMPORT  __main
3 LDR     R0, =SystemInit
4 BLX     R0
5 LDR     R0, =__main
6 BX      R0
```

You can comment lines 1,3,4 with ; symbol.

Actually, function SystemInit usually is part of STM Peripheral library and it's aimed to initialize all periphery that you need. Without it, you'll have to do initialization yourself.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is too late, but:
You should check Keil uVision installation folder and there are files with SystemInit function on board for all (I hope) vendors:)

*~\Keil\ARM\Startup\ST\STM32F2xx\system_stm32f2xx.c*