# Missing SystemInit function from LPC1788 startup file? where can i find it?

Tags: c, embedded, keil

I am using LPC1788 micro-controller with Keil4, when i create a project Keil adds a file called "startup_LPC177x_8x.s". In this file at one stage a IMPORT command is trying to import SystemInit, but when i compile, i get an error as follow:

```
 compiling main.c...
 main.c(6): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline
 linking...
 project_1.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol SystemInit (referred from startup_lpc177x_8x.o).
 Target not created
```

the piece of code is as follow:

```
 Reset_Handler   PROC
                 EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]
                 IMPORT  SystemInit
                 IMPORT  __main
                 LDR     R0, =SystemInit
                 BLX     R0
                 LDR     R0, =__main
                 BX      R0
                 ENDP
```

I have included the header file "lpc177x_8x.h" in my project.

Please guide me friends ...i am new to Keil...thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbol SystemInit(referred from startup\_stm32f2xx.o) while building using Keil STM32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889732/undefined-symbol-systeminitreferred-from-startup-stm32f2xx-o-while-building-us)

Answer (score 0):

It is an `IMPORT` symbol in this file - that is it defined elsewhere.

It will probably be in a file named system_LPC177x_8x.c or similar; it may need customisation for your project to set the PLL and initialise external memory interfaces, and other clock dependent features.

It is normally included in your project automatically if you ask for start-up files to be included when you create the project; otherwise it will be in the CMSIS target specific support folder in the Keil ARM-MDK installation, in this case I would guess:  `CMSIS\CM3\DeviceSupport\NXP\LPC17xx\` or similar, the exact directory structure has changed between CMSIS versions.

Answer (score 0):

depends on where you installed Keil.

here is the address in my computer：

D:\Program Files\keil\ARM\INC\NXP\LPC17xx

(here contains the header files you use)

D:\Program Files\keil\ARM\Startup\NXP\LPC17xx

(here contains startup files you use, the SystemInit function is defined here in the system_LPC13xx.c)